# How do you add a custom UIViewController to existing XIB?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I am just getting my feet wet with MonoTouch and have the most basic of questions.  In their tutorials, they cover adding controls to the XIB directly through XCode's Interface Builder.  However, I cannot figure out how to add a custom control to the XIB.

I have seen a number of examples of subclassing the base UICollectionView to customize it for your own purposes, and have done this in C# code in my project.  My question is, how do I add that specific subclass of the UICollectionView to the XIB for use in the project?

Comment: I'll put it in the comments, since I don't remember the proper tab, but there is a tab in the side view (where it contains information about size, and information specific to that control) There is a tab that says what class the view control is, you can change that to be your subclass.

Comment: So I add a normal UICollectionView to the screen, then change a property to reference MyUICollectionView defined in my project?  Perhaps the "Custom Class" property on the Identity Inspector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a normal UIView, the basic steps you need to go through are:

1. Create your custom view in C# as a class

   ```
   public class MyView
   {
   }
   ```
2. Add the UIView base class to it, add a Register attribute and add two constructors:

   ```
   [Register("MyView")]
   public class MyView : UIView
   {
       public MyView() {}
       public MyView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {}
   }
   ```
3. To make it do something useful, then add a Draw implementation:

   ```
   public override Draw(RectangleF rect)
   {
       var context = UIGraphics.CurrentGraphics();
       UIColor.Red.SetFill();
       context.FillEclipseInRect(rect);
   }
   ```
4. Save and Build your project
5. Now in the XIB editor for the UIViewController in which you want to use your custom view, add a UIView to the design surface
6. Select that UIView and in the Identity Inspector, set the UIView's "Custom Class" to "MyView"
7. Save everything in xCode
8. Return to MonoDevelop, build and run

There's a video of this flow available at:
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggwO46dd-50&feature=youtube_gdata

For a custom UICollectionView,  UILabel, UITableViewCell,  or any other UIView base class, then you follow similar steps, just with a different base class and with different constructors too in order to support the specific View.

For a video about custom Table cells, see: http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html